# I have a dualboot PC with working MBR, won't restart from Win7

Tags: windows-7

I can shutdown from both Windows XP and Windows 7. I can restart from Windows XP. When I try to restart from Windows 7 the screen goes on standby and never comes back. Never shows post or any noise coming from hard drive. I have to power off physically to get it to post. Running in safe mode didn't help. Running troubleshooter didn't help. Sometimes powering off doesn't help and I have to do it twice. This ONLY happens when I issue a restart command from Windows 7. There are no extraneous autoexec.bat and config.sys only says files=40. I've tried removing unnecessary programs from msconfig. Won't even restart from safe mode. Odd problem. No major updates before it started.

Comment: We need more history on your dual boot installation, things like which OS was installed first, did this problem start happening right after installing the second OS, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is something wrong with the installation. Did this problem occur recently or it has been this way since you installed win7?

First of all you could try to use [Startup Repair](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/startup-repair) to check for any installation problems.

Second of all, you can try to modify the order of the OS in the bootloader.